# In what suttas are the "4 resolves" (adhiṭṭhānī) discussed?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, right-intention

I have heard this list discussed in Dharma talks like this one:
[Gil Fronsdal: The Four Resolves (Recorded: Monday, June 12, 2017)](https://www.audiodharma.org/talks/audio_player/7876.html)

But when I tried to find suttas on this subject, I could only find 1 in which the existence of the "4 resolves" was mentioned.
[DN 33: Saṅgāti Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhi%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na#Digha_Nikaya_analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MN 140](https://suttacentral.net/mn140/en/bodhi).

> Bhikkhu, this person has four foundations.’ So it was said. And with
> reference to what was this said? There are the foundation of wisdom,
> the foundation of truth, the foundation of relinquishment, and the
> foundation of peace. So it was with reference to this that it was
> said: ‘Bhikkhu, this person has four foundations.’
>
> 'One should not neglect wisdom, should preserve truth, should
> cultivate relinquishment, and should train for peace.’ So it was said.
> And with reference to what was this said?